PCAPNG package in Python
Is it possible to extract frame attributes from pcapng file using python-pcapng package? If yes, how is it possible to do so? Are there any better packages for this purpose??
I can't find anything in this documentation https://readthedocs.org/projects/python-pcapng/downloads/pdf/latest/.

what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example

have you tried the examples from the official git repo ?  https://github.com/rshk/python-pcapng/tree/master/examples
